# How to tell PhpStorm about implementation details? (magic methods)

Tags: phpstorm

I have an object "User" that has attributes whose accessability is declared as protected but which can be set directly via a magic __set-method.

[image]

Now PhpStorm signals this apparent inconsistency with a big red column on the right side.

Is it possible to explain to PhpStorm what is going on so this is not shown as an error any more?

---

**EDIT :**

I use PhpStorm 2.1.4

okay here is some code that exemplifies the issue (together with the so far suggested workaround from Alexey which sadly doesn't do it for me):

**c.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @property mixed $a
 */
class c1
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct() { $this->a = __CLASS__; }

    public function __get($n) { return $this->{$n}; }
}

/**
 * @property $a mixed
 */
class c2
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct() { $this->a = __CLASS__; }

    public function __get($n) { return $this->{$n}; }
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require "c.php";

$c1 = new c1();
var_dump($c1->a);

$c2 = new c2();
var_dump($c2->a);
```

**and the output:**

```
string 'c1' (length=2)
string 'c2' (length=2)
```

and **how it looks** like in PhpStorm:

[image]

**my goal:**

either having PhpStorm "understand" the design or just getting rid of those annoying red marks everywhere while not impairing the error detection apart from this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is now working in PHPStorm 3 :)**

Unfortunately this is a open request in our tracker, see
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-4468

The only way to avoid this warnings now, is to add `@property` to $user's class declaration. i.e.

```
/**
 * @property $name string
 */
class User {
    protected $name; 
}
$user = new User();
$user->name = "me";
```

Comment: the workaround doesn't change that PHPStorm interpretes the access as faulty.

Comment: Well, I added complete example. And I'm the developer of these checks in IDE. If it doesn't work for you - go to our tracker and provide your code to reproduce.

Comment: What if it's a overloaded method instead of property (with the same name) defined as protected? `protected function foo($a, $b);` and `public function __call($m, $p)` I'm unable to bypass this error without changing all method's names.

Comment: So how to tell IDE to hide these checks without source class annotation modifying? I.e. original class has protected methods/fields but by some magic conversions they become public and guaranteedto work. How to hide these checks and red marks?